# Работа с файлами С++ (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

Программа должна открывать для чтения и записи ".txt" файл, в котором хранятся модели и цены ноутбуков, и при необходимости вызывать окно добавления данных в файл и сохранять этот файл.

Проблемы с которыми столкнулся:

1. При открытии ".txt" файла в кодировке ANSII в окно выводится куча непонятных символов, однако, если сохранить файл как UNICODE, открывает без проблем. Необходимо поправить код, чтобы программа без проблем открывала кодировку ANSII
2. Возможно из-за конфликта кодировок при добавлении данных в поле EDIT_2 и последующем их сохранении вместе цены ноутбука, сохраняется рандомный символ.

```
 using namespace std;

// Глобальные переменные:  
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // текущий экземпляр  
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // Текст строки заголовка  
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // имя класса главного окна  

ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);  
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);  
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);  
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);  
BOOL CALLBACK DlgProcAdd(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);  

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,  
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,  
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,  
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)    
{  
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);  
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);  

    // Инициализация глобальных строк  
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);  
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_TEST, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);  
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);  

    // Выполнить инициализацию приложения:  
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))  
    {  
        return FALSE;  
    }  
    MSG msg;  

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TEST));  

    // Цикл основного сообщения:  
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))  
    {  
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))  
        {  
            TranslateMessage(&msg);  
            DispatchMessage(&msg);  
        }  
    }  

    return (int) msg.wParam;  
}  

//  
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: MyRegisterClass()  
//  
//  НАЗНАЧЕНИЕ: регистрирует класс окна.  
//  
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)  
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE (IDC_POINTER));
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_TEST);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   ФУНКЦИЯ: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   НАЗНАЧЕНИЕ: сохраняет обработку экземпляра и создает главное окно.
//
//   КОММЕНТАРИИ:
//
//        В данной функции дескриптор экземпляра сохраняется в глобальной переменной, а также
//        создается и выводится на экран главное окно программы.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Сохранить дескриптор экземпляра в глобальной переменной

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}
//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  НАЗНАЧЕНИЕ:  обрабатывает сообщения в главном окне.
//
//  WM_COMMAND — обработать меню приложения
//  WM_PAINT — отрисовать главное окно
//  WM_DESTROY — отправить сообщение о выходе и вернуться
//
//
    //Создаем пользовательскую структуру

    struct laptop {
        TCHAR model[20];
        int price;
    }ms,laptops[25];
    const int N = 10; //количество ноутбуков на складе
    laptop Stock[N];//Массив для всех ноутбуков
    laptop Unit; //Структурные переменные
    DWORD dwCount;


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    HMENU hSubMenu, hMenu;
    int xpos, ypos;
    //Переменные для стандартных диалогов "Open", "Save As"
    static OPENFILENAME file;
    static TCHAR name[MAX_PATH];
    static HANDLE hFile;
    BOOL succes;
    TCHAR szT[200];
    int i = 0;
    int y = 0;
    DWORD dw = 0;
    const DWORD MaxLength = 250;
    static wchar_t text[MaxLength] ;    
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        xpos = LOWORD(lParam);
        ypos = HIWORD(lParam);
        //Загрузим меню из ресурсов приложения
        hMenu = LoadMenu(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(Context_Menu));
        //Получим дескриптор подменю
        hSubMenu = GetSubMenu(hMenu, 0);
        //Отобразим контекстное меню
        TrackPopupMenu(hSubMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN, xpos, ypos, 0, hWnd, NULL);
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:

    {
        file.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
        file.hInstance = hInst;
        file.lpstrFilter = _T("Text\0*.txt");
        file.lpstrFile = name;
        file.nMaxFile = 256;
        file.lpstrInitialDir = _T(".\\");
        file.lpstrDefExt = _T("txt");
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Разобрать выбор в меню:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case ID_32779:
            file.lpstrTitle = _T("Открыть файл для чтения");
            file.Flags = OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
            if (!GetOpenFileName(&file)) return 1;
            hFile = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
            hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
            //ReadFile(hFile, &laptops, sizeof(laptops), &dwCount, NULL);
            while (ReadFile(hFile, &laptops, sizeof(laptops), &dwCount, NULL) && dwCount != 0)
            {

            TextOut(hdc, 0, y, (LPWSTR)laptops, dwCount);
                y += 16;

            }
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
            break;
        case ID_32792:
            file.lpstrTitle = _T("Сохранить файл");
            file.Flags = OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
            succes = GetSaveFileName(&file);
            if (succes)
            {
                MessageBox(hWnd, file.lpstrFile, TEXT("Файл сохраняется с именем:"), MB_OK);
                hFile = CreateFile(file.lpstrFile, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);
                SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_END);
                WriteFile(hFile, &laptops, sizeof(laptops), &dwCount, NULL);
                CloseHandle(hFile);
            }
            else
                MessageBox(hWnd, ESC_OF, TEXT("Отказ от выбора или ошибка"), MB_ICONWARNING);
            break;
            // Разобрать выбор в меню:
        case ID_32807:
        {
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hWnd, DlgProcAdd);
            break;

        }
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        }

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Добавьте сюда любой код прорисовки, использующий HDC...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {   PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
    }
}

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProcAdd(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND hModel, hPrice;
    TCHAR str[20];
    DWORD dw = 0;
    static HANDLE hFile;
    static int j = 0;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        hModel = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_VVOD1);
        hPrice = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_VVOD2);
        SetFocus(hModel);
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK)
        {
            GetDlgItemText(hWnd, IDC_VVOD1, (LPWSTR)ms.model, sizeof(ms.model));
            ms.price = GetDlgItemInt(hWnd, IDC_VVOD2, 0, 0);
            FlushFileBuffers(hFile);
            WriteFile(hFile, &ms, sizeof(ms), &dw, NULL);
            SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_END);
            laptops[j++] = ms;
            EndDialog(hWnd, 0);
        }
        else if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hWnd, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        return TRUE;
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(hWnd, 0);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
// Обработчик сообщений для окна "О программе".
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Вам необходимо преобразовать текст в юникод перед выводом. Это можно сделать при помощи функции [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Если вас не затруднит, то распишите подробнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема на самом деле не связана с кодировками. Вы пишете, что файл "txt", но при этом работаете с ним как с бинарным. Также вы пытаетесь интерпретировать бинарные данные структуры как текст (*LPWSTR*), что не может быть хорошей идеей. Поля, содержащие юникод-строки, корректно выводятся по случайности, так как для них бинарное и текстовое представление в данном случае совпадают.

Чтобы сделать все правильно, нужно сначала определиться, бинарный файл вам нужен или текстовый. Если на самом деле текстовый, то вместо скармливания `WriteFile` структуры *laptop* нужно преобразовать все ее члены в строку и записывать в файл уже строки, следуя определенному формату. При считывании наоборот, делить текст на отдельные элементы на основе этого формата и преобразовывать их в соответствующий тип. Проще всего это будет реализовать с использованием функций [fprintf_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) и [fscanf_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (ANSI), либо `fwprintf_s` и `fwscanf_s` (Unicode).